# Есть ли законодательные ограничения на использование @font-face?

Tags: html, css, шрифты, юридические-аспекты

Пока ещё не вник в тему глубоко, но в какой-то статье я читал, что при использовании нестандартных шрифтов они растрезуются, а если нужно использовать без растрезации, то шрифты придётся покупать (даже такие известные, как `Tahoma` , встречаются в IT-магазинах). Поправьте меня в ответе, если я сказал чушь.

Вопрос такой: а можно ли без нарушения авторского права свободно брать любые шрифты из `Windows/Fonts` и через `@font-face` вставлять их себе на сайт?

Comment: ну насколько я знаю, шрифты имеют лицензию распространения, аналогичные коду программам и так далее. Смотрите конкретно в лицензию конкретного шрифта. TNR вроде бы нельзя распространять, Arial можно и так далее.

Comment: Вы бы лучше у юриста спросили. Если я скажу, что можно, а по факту нельзя, сядете в тюрьму вы, а не я. Спрашивайте у специалиста лучше.

Comment: Остаётся непонятным смысл вставки стандартных Windows шрифтов в @font-face

Comment: Мда, я смотрю вопрос действительно имеет актуальность.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, в Windows/Fonts не обязательно лежат только стандартные шрифты. Получается вполне рабочая схема - сначала устанавливаем на компьютер нужные шрифты, а потом забираем их из Windows/Fonts :D

Comment: @VladD прав, на такой вопрос должен отвечать юрист. Но тут возникает ещё вопрос -- законы какой страны или стран должен соблюдать сайт. Потому что есть компания, владеющая сайтом, есть компания-хостер, есть клиент -- все они могут быть из различных стран. Плюс законы даже разных штатов в деталях различаются. И с этим тоже нужно к юристу конечно.

Comment: Нашел кое-что по теме. В [этой](https://habrahabr.ru/post/173271/) статье автор тоже, по меньшей мере, тоже сомневается в законности использовании @font-face.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала имеет смысл поискать подходящие шрифты и картинки, распространяемые под свободными лицензиями. Их главная черта — возможность законно и бесплатно использовать чужие произведения, не нарушив закон. Но, как и в любых лицензиях, в них содержатся ограничения, которые важно соблюсти.

Например, лицензия «Креатив Комонс — без производных произведений» запрещает распространять производные произведения, а лицензия «МИТ» заставляет публиковать текст лицензии во всех экземплярах произведений. Кажется, вам подойдут произведения под лицензиями «Креатив Комонс» всех видов и «МИТ».

Ещё один способ решить вашу задачу — свободное использование чужих произведений. Проще всего обстоят дела с картинками. Если вы используете их, чтобы проиллюстрировать «в целях раскрытия творческого замысла», сохранив автора и указав источник, а объём цитирования оправдан его целью, вы не нарушите закон.

Руководство по лицензиям
Лицензии «Креатив комонс»
Лицензия «МИТ»
1273 ГК
1274 ГК
А ещё закон разрешает образовательным учреждениям использовать материалы из периодических изданий в некоммерческих целях. При этом закон не ограничивает такое использование максимальным объёмом цитирования. Необходимость сослаться на автора и источник заимствования всё равно остаётся.

Сложнее со шрифтами. Одно дело — набрать пару букв или слов, чтобы рассказать о его особенностях в статье об отличиях шрифтов с засечками от шрифтов без засечек. По-моему, это классический вариант цитирования в информационных или образовательных целях, которым не удивить ни правообладателя, ни судью.

Но совсем другое — набрать платным шрифтом заголовок или пару статей исключительно ради собственного чувства прекрасного. Мне кажется, что это выходит за рамки свободного использования и если что-то пойдёт не так, суд будет не на вашей стороне.

Возможно, вам подойдёт самый простой и надёжный способ использовать платные шрифты — заплатить за них. Скорее всего, это дешевле, чем вы думаете — многие правообладатели предоставляют скидку.

Ещё один способ решить задачу — попросить автора предоставить вам право использовать шрифт или картинку бесплатно. Удивительно, но в моей практике количество отказов по таким случаям меньше, чем положительных ответов.

1275·6 ГК РФ
Незаконное использование чужих произведений — не только потеря репутации и авторитета, но и удар по кошельку. Размер компенсации, которую придётся выплатить правообладателю за нарушение исключительного права — от десяти тысяч до пяти миллионов рублей за каждое нарушение.

[оригинал](http://artgorbunov.ru/bb/soviet/20160604/)

Comment: Забавно, что отвечая про лицензионные соглашения на шрифты, вы стянули текст с другого сайта, даже не поменяв лицо повествования *("Удивительно, но **в моей** практике")* - при том что на том сайте нигде нет разрешения на подобное действие.

Comment: так я указал источник. Автор высказывался что не против того что его процитируют, в случае ссылки на оригинал. Грамотный разъяснение на мой взгляд. Не искажал текст нарочно.

Comment: Во-первых, то, что сделали вы - это не цитирование. Во-вторых, на этом сайте есть свое лицензионное соглашение, под которым все вопросы и ответы публикуются - а автор давал разрешение только на цитирование, но не на публикацию под другой лицензией.